# Get all tasks where user_id isn't 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request

I want to select all tasks where user_id isn't 1.

I've tried to find my answer in the console, but I couldn't figure it out.

Things I've tried:

```
@otherUsers = User.offset(1).pluck(:id)<br>
User.find(@otherUsers).tasks
```

Comment: For the record, 1 in `User.offset(1)` is not necessarily related to the user's id, it will skip the first user (based on how the database defines first) and return the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have try this ?

```
Client.where("user_id != ?", 1)
```

For all user where user_id isn't 1.

Best regards.